# Problems installing snappy on python on Alpine Linux

Tags: python, linux, pip, alpine-linux, snappy

When i am trying to install Snappy on alpine linux using: 
pip install snappy
I am getting the following error when it tries to install a required package called cypari.

I installed snappy from "apk add snappy"

```
    gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -g -DNDEBUG -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -g -fPIC -Ilibcache/pari64/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c cypari_src/_pari.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/cypari_src/_pari.o
In file included from cypari_src/_pari.c:460:0:
cypari_src/implementation.c:47:22: fatal error: execinfo.h: No such file or directory
 #include <execinfo.h>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved this problem by running `apk add libexecinfo libexecinfo-dev`

Then using `apk add snappy`

Then using `pip install python-snappy`

if you use `pip install snappy` it installs a completely different library which is [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/snappy)

Answer (score 5):

Combining previous answers, this minimal Dockerfile works for me

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache g++ snappy-dev && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir --ignore-installed python-snappy
```

Comment: Cool! BTW. `apk add --no-cache g++ snappy-dev` is enough as `snappy` being a dependency of `snappy-dev`.

Comment: Are g++ and snappy-dev required after installing python-snappy? I mean, can I remove them after installing python-snappy to reduce docker image size?

Comment: @AhmedHammad not sure, but you can try and let us know!:)

Comment: I tried it, but docker image size was not reduced!

Comment: How did you try it? maybe doing it in the same command? `apk add --no-cache g++ snappy-dev && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir --ignore-installed python-snappy && apk del g++ snappy-dev` ?

Answer (score 0):

Installing execinfo-dev suffice, since execinfo.h is in that package.

You can check it here:

http://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=execinfo.h&path=&name=&branch=&repo=&arch=

```
apk add snappy
```

will install the package, so you don't need to:

```
pip install snappy
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the answer from @dwardu, I also had to install the `snappy-dev` package. That fixed this error I was getting from `pip install`:

`snappy-c.h: No such file or directory`